# In Maven project will adding the latest versions of dependencies guarantee a trouble free project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, struts

I am sure this is a very basic but important question, answer to which i dont know.
I want to know the answer because i spent several **days and nights trying to fix the problems arising in my projects due to version problems in Maven artifacts**. First i had problem integrating struts + hibernate. Now with SPRING+HIBERNATE. When i take a sample working project as base, it works fine. 
But when **in a zealous attempt, i updated the pom.xml with all the latest versions of dependencies, i get plenty of errors**, and i try to fix them one by one and end up adding more dependencies/jars in the process which i think leads to the problem. But why it leads to problem, i am not sure. But for now, i have reverted to the original working (but older) versions of dependencies in pom.xml and everything has started working fine.

My question is **`In Maven project will adding the latest versions of dependencies guarantee a trouble free project??`**

My experience in Maven is not much. I have only experience in importing projects/changing dependencies.

**Or is creating projects through Maven from scratch a panacea to my problems?(in which i dont have much experience)**

Comment: Integration between different framework is not directly related with maven. Individual frameworks and you as a developer is responsible.

Comment: When something doesn't work, the first thing to do is to read the error message. Ignoring it and upgrading the version of every possible dependency is surely not the way to go.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao i think archetypes in Maven are exactly that (templates for different technologies when working together)...??

Comment: @Amar: but Maven will never guarantee that all the jars you're using are compatible with each other, and even less that the code you're using is correct.

Comment: @JBNizet The problem in Netbeans was that i used the inbuilt framework versions of struts & hibernate & hoped everything would inter-work smoothly which it didn't (I am not sure how it is with Eclipse..). sometimes, struts jars wanted later hibernate jars & sometimes earlier jars (which was what i understood from the error messages). Fixing one problem after another, it took days just to have a right combination of working jars of two different  technologies. for freshers atleast. I wonder how experts do it... Do they also get errors like i do or do they have any sure shot solution?Any inputs?

Comment: @JBNizet It is interesting to note that even with Maven archetypes there is no guarantee. So i am not the only one in the world facing the problems i do. Thank GOD!!

Comment: Agree with @JB Nizet..you need to look into the exact error and work forward. As of maven, it handles the transitive dependency..that is if your dependency have further dependency it will try to resolve them too.. fetching from your local repository or other configured repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using the most recent versions of dependencies will not necessarily guarantee a trouble free project. If you are going to include a dependency that requires integration with another dependency, you will usually need to do some research before you determine what version to include. For example, if you had a Spring 3.0+ dependency in your pom.xml and you were going to add a version of Hibernate that works correctly with Spring, you could go to the  Spring documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) and read about what versions of Hibernate will work with that version of Spring. Typically if a framework like Spring takes the time to provide integration with another framework like Hibernate, they will include documentation detailing what versions of the framework will correctly interact with the other framework.

Comment: Agreed. In link it mentions... `As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.2 or later.`  Now If i jump to the latest Hibernate version 4.0 & use it may be it does not support backward compatibility and may be Hibernate 4.0 require spring 3.2+.. So i think on seeing `Hibernate 3.2 or later` i should pick only 3.2 and not the latest Hibernate.. Am i right in assuming so @drembert ???

Comment: I think you will be fine with any version of Hibernate that has a version greater than 3.2 and less than 4.0. I'm pretty sure Spring has another set of classes for integration with 4.xx